# Exchange 2010 interprets display name incorrectly

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

I've been investigating an issue with emails showing up in outlook as **first.name@** (without the email address), and it seems the email address is being sent as the display name like so

```
first.name@email.com <first.name@email.com>
```

Within Outlook, the To: field is shown like so:

```
first.name@ <email.com first.name@email.com>
```

This seems to only be an issue in Exchange 2010 (the company I work for still uses it), I did a few tests using Gmail and it just fine.

```
"first.name@gmail.com" <first.name@gmail.com>
```

Is this a specific issue to Exchange 2010? i.e would this issue be resolved in a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyone in the organization who has the same problem as you? Whether the email address has never been displayed properly before?

I also want to know that whether the recipient is inside or outside your organization?
If inside, how many users show the wrong display, one or more?

How did you enter the TO field, enter the full email address or use auto complete or choose in the address book?

If you use the outlook cache, you can try to [Clear Outlook Recipient Cache](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/office-365-clear-outlook-recipient-cache/)

What’s more, try to use OWA, check how the email address displayed in it, properly or also wrongly. 
Last, the low version of outlook may cause the problem as well. If so, just update your outlook version.

Comment: It appears to be affecting everyone in the organisation. We use SendGrid to send transactional emails both internally and externally. We spotted that the email address was being sent with the email address as the display name (this was being set by us), which appears to be misinterpreted by Exchange 2010. Its the same for Outlook and OWA. We have plans to upgrade to  Exchange 2013 (sigh), but curious to know if we will still see this problem.

Comment: As you mentioned that you spotted that the email address was being sent with the email address as the display name (this was being set by us), where and how did you set this, and tell the detailed configuration. 
Does this problem exist from the beginning or after some configuration?
According to my experience, if you upgrade your Exchange server without changing any configuration, the problem may still exist.